# Connecting Amazons EKS to use Azures Active Directory for RBAC

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, rbac, azure-aks, amazon-eks

I currently have an issue where Azure Active Directory is being used to integrate into Kubernetes RBAC (on prem) and there is a need to move to the cloud, for various reasons the decision has been made to use EKS from Amazon, is there a way to integrate Azure AD and EKS?

So currently I have tried two routes, one being setting up the identity provider on AWS to connect to Azure AD, and the other I am looking at Dex, but I feel these are all really hacky as with this issue on Github https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/166 it would be the easiest to just set the flags:

- oidc-issuer-url
- oidc-client-id
- oidc-ca-file
- oidc-username-claim
- oidc-groups-claim

What I would like to see is being able to use Azure AD Groups in Roles on the EKS cluster

Comment: I'd be curious how you ended up proceeding. I came across [Guard](https://github.com/appscode/guard) a while ago, not sure if it would help with what you're looking for.

Comment: Well we got a bit of a hacky version up using Dex, but in the end, decided against using EKS (we hosted our own k8s on EC2 instances). However I see this has now been moved to "comming soon" on the linked issue